# Java BufferedFileReader skips first line

Tags: java, swing, io, text-files

I'm trying to use the BufferedFileReader to read a Document with saved Information. It's working good, but it always skips the first line of the code. Is it because I'm calling readLine() in the for loop? If so how could I change it?

```
private void createViewUser() {

    String[] stringFirstName = new String[10];
    String[] stringName = new String[10];
    String[] stringAge= new String[10];

    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        for (int i = 0; br.readLine() != null; i++) {

            stringFirstName[i] = br.readLine();
            stringName[i] = br.readLine();
            stringAge[i] = br.readLine();

            firstname[i] = new JTextField();
            firstname[i].setBounds(100, 100 + 50 * i, 100, 30);
            view.add(firstname[i]);

            name[i] = new JTextField();
            name[i].setBounds(200, 100 + 50 * i, 100, 30);
            view.add(name[i]);

            age[i] = new JTextField();
            age[i].setBounds(300, 100 + 50 * i, 100, 30);
            view.add(age[i]);

            firstname[i].setText(stringFirstName[i]);
            name[i].setText(stringName[i]);
            age[i].setText(stringAge[i]);

        }
        fr.close();
        br.close();



    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but your component positioning, using null layout and `setBounds` is a very bad thing to do as by doing so, you create a rigid, hard to debug or enhance program, one that appears bad on computers with different resolutions and one that fights against the GUI library that you're using. If this were my program and I were trying to display tabular data as you are doing, why not more simply create and display this information in a JTable?

Comment: Also you're using parallel arrays, a bad design choice, and instead should consider creating a class to hold the first and last names as well as the age in a single object. Then create an ArrayList of these objects.

Comment: Yes you're right, but it was just my first idea and I wanted to complete it and then maybe change it. Thanks anyways I'll try it soon. And I'm just starting and never worked with ArrayLists so I tried to avoid them

Answer (score 0):

Exactly,  each time  before going  into the for loop  your program  reads a line and checks if it is not null. 
More you will also skip a line because of this condition. (not sure if it's desired or not)
You kinda got the answer yourself ;)

Comment: Okay and what can I use instead?

Answer (score 0):

you're reading first line in the for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; br.readLine() /* HERE*/ != null; i++) {
```

You could do something like this:

```
String line = br.readLine();
for(int i = 0; line != null ; i++){
       stringFirstName[i] = line;
       line = br.readLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can init String var to fix it:

```
String line = br.readLine();

for (int i = 0; line != null; i++) {
    stringFirstName[i] = line;
    stringName[i] = br.readLine();
    stringAge[i] = br.readLine();
```

It's doesn't work because it's load first line on for loop verification `for (int i = 0; br.readLine() != null; i++) {`

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your question involves several steps, but the most important issue for your purposes is how to efficiently *and safely* read data held in a text file when the data is presented in groups of three lines, something like:

```
first_name_1
last_name_1
age_1
first_name_2
last_name_2
age_2
first_name_3
last_name_3
age_3
first_name_4
last_name_4
age_4
```

where of course the names are replaced with real names, and likewise the age_? is replaced with a real number.

If you're going to go the BufferedReader route, I think that the safest thing to do is get **all three Strings** in each grouping within the while loop's boolean condition, something like:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(....);

// declare empty Strings first
String firstName = "";
String lastName = "";
String ageString = ""; // need to get age *first* as a String

while ((firstName = reader.readLine()) != null         // get all 3 Strings here
        && (lastName = reader.readLine()) != null
        && (ageString = reader.readLine()) != null) {  // boolean condition ends here
    int age = Integer.parseInt(ageString.trim());    // NumberFormatException risk here

    // ....

}
```

This way, if any of the Strings in the text file are missing, the whole while loop ends, and bad data is not obtained.

Other recommendations, create a plain-old Java object to hold your Person data, the names and the age, a class with 3 fields, 2 that are Strings for the names, and one int field for the age. Give it a decent constructor, getter methods.... For example:

```
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, int age) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", age=" + age + "]";
    }

}
```

This way, the while loop above could be used to simply create Person objects:

```
List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();  // an ArrayList of Person to hold the data

while ((firstName = reader.readLine()) != null              // get all 3 Strings here
        && (lastName = reader.readLine()) != null
        && (ageString = reader.readLine()) != null) {       // the while loop ends here
    int age = Integer.parseInt(ageString.trim());

    Person person = new Person(firstName, lastName, age);   // create a new Person object 
    persons.add(person);                                    // put it into the arraylist
}
```

OK, how about displaying this information into a JTable -- that's easy.

Create a DefaultTableModel with the correct column names:

```
private static final String[] COL_NAMES = { "First Name", "Last Name", "Age" };
private DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(COL_NAMES, 0);
```

and then create a JTable with this model:

```
private JTable table = new JTable(model);
```

Then iterate through the `ArrayList<Person>` and fill our model with data:

```
for (Person person : personList) {
    Vector<Object> rowData = new Vector<>();
    rowData.add(person.getFirstName());
    rowData.add(person.getLastName());
    rowData.add(person.getAge());
    model.addRow(rowData);
}
```

and the JTable is created and filled with data, just like that.

OK, assuming a data file called PersonData.txt that is located in the same directory as our class files, like so:

[image]

And assuming that this file  holds our data like so:

```
John
Smith
21
Fred
Flinstone
53
Barny
Rubble
52
Mary
Contrary
22
Bo
Peep
12
Donald
Trump
75
Donald
Duck
40
Mickey
Mouse
45
Minnie
Mouse
41
Ebenezer
Scrooge
80
Bob
Cratchit
33
Ralph
Kramden
55
Alice
Kramden
48
Ed
Norton
54
```

Then using our Person.java class, we can create a GUI to hold and display our data like so:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class PersonDisplay extends JPanel {
    private static final String[] COL_NAMES = { "First Name", "Last Name", "Age" };
    private static final String PERSON_DATA_PATH = "PersonData.txt";
    private DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(COL_NAMES, 0);
    private JTable table = new JTable(model);

    public PersonDisplay(List<Person> personList) {
        for (Person person : personList) {
            Vector<Object> rowData = new Vector<>();
            rowData.add(person.getFirstName());
            rowData.add(person.getLastName());
            rowData.add(person.getAge());
            model.addRow(rowData);
        }

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new JScrollPane(table));
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui(List<Person> personList) {
        PersonDisplay mainPanel = new PersonDisplay(personList);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Person Display");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static List<Person> readInPersons(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String firstName = "";
        String lastName = "";
        String ageString = "";

        while ((firstName = reader.readLine()) != null 
                && (lastName = reader.readLine()) != null
                && (ageString = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            int age = Integer.parseInt(ageString.trim());
            Person person = new Person(firstName, lastName, age);
            persons.add(person);
        }

        return persons;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = PersonDisplay.class.getResourceAsStream(PERSON_DATA_PATH);
            List<Person> personList = readInPersons(inputStream);
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui(personList));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and when displayed, it would look like:

[image]